# Différents usages de « en + participe présent »

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, participe-présent, en

> Elle n'a pas fait le ménage, en laissant le soin à son mari.

Cette phrase me semble correcte, non pas qu'elle soit imperfectible ; est-ce le cas?
Le "en" rapporterait au "ménage", pas comme le "en" de la phrase:

> Elle n'a pas fait le ménage, *en* laissant le soin à son mari de le faire.

Comment: D'accord pour la première, mais pour la seconde le "en" est superflu, voire faux... Le "en" remplace dans la première "faire le ménage", donc la seconde devrait s'écrire "Elle n'a pas fait le ménage, laissant le soin à son mari de le faire". La répétition de "faire" rend la première plus élégante. On pourrait aussi écrire je pense "Elle n'a pas fait le ménage, laissant ce soin à son mari".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est tout à fait exact.

Ce qui la rend perfectible tient toutefois uniquement au style: cette formulation sonne pour moi très (trop) classique et littéraire. Si je devais la corriger dans un texte, j'écrirais probablement *préférant en laisser le soin*.